# html "display: table" If we do not set the height, we know that it appears the same. But it seems different from what I know

Tags: html

My structure is

```
<div height : 240px>
   <div display : table>           
      <div display : table-row>             
         <div display : table-cell>
      <div display : table-row>            
         <div display : table-cell>
      <div display : table-row>          
         <div display : table-cell>
```

I know that 80px should come out.

but table-row height is not 80px..

why ,,?

Comment: What is the issue here? where is 80px?

Comment: Three table-cells are 80px each. But now the first table-cell height is 100px and the rest is 70px.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the height for the `div` which has the `display: table`.

```css
/* DivTable.com */
.divTable{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
}
.divTableRow {
 display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
 display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
 display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.divTableHeading {
 display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableFoot {
 display: table-footer-group;
}
.divTableBody {
 display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```